# Positive semi/definite matrix claim.

Tags: matrices, analysis

If $A$, $B$ is positive semidefinite (PSD) and $C$ is positive definite (PD), all are  Hermitian, complex valued. I want to claim that $$(B+C)^{-1/2}A(B+C)^{-1/2}$$ is PD. (I am sure it is PSD but looking for PD).

My attempt: I know $B+C$ is PD so $(B+C)^{-1}$ is PD then I know $(B+C)^{-1/2}$ is PD. That is as far as I went.

Thanks in advance to any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition: If $H$ is HPD and $A$ is HPSD, then of course $HAH$ is HPSD as well since $0\leq x^*HAHx=(Hx)^*A(Hx)$ for all $x$.

EDIT: You can replace HPSD with HPD, however, the transformed matrix cannot be HPD if $A$ is HPSD only and singular. In such a case, there is a nonzero $y$ such that $Ay=0$. So: $A(B+C)^{-1/2}x=0$, $x^*(B+C)^{-1/2}A(B+C)^{-1/2}x=0$, where $x=(B+C)^{1/2}y\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, but In my case $A$ is not PD it is PSD.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was writing faster than thinking :D

Comment: Thanks. So do you mean it will never be PD?

Comment: Anyway, the point is to use the fact that $0\leq y^*Ay$ with $y=Hy$, where $y=(B+C)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. As I claim in the question I know that the result is PSD, I want the case when it will be PD.

Comment: Ah that, no it won't. If $A$ is singular then the transformed matrix is of course singular as well. So if $A$ is PD, then $(B+C)^{-1/2}A(B+C)^{-1/2}$ is PD. But if $A$ is PSD, then $(B+C)^{-1/2}A(B+C)^{-1/2}$ is PSD only. A simple example would be with $A=0$.

Answer (score 1):

- Claim 1. If $B$ is PSD and $C$ is PD then $B+C$ is PD.
- Claim 2. $(B+C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is PD. (Inverse of a PD matrix is PD)
- Claim 3a. If $A$ is PD, then $(B+C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}A(B+C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is PD.
- Claim 3b. If $A$ is PSD, then $(B+C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}A(B+C)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is PSD.

*Pretty much rephrasing the answer in the comment by Pavel Jiranek.*